# Power Automate - Sharepoint List item is created twice

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I have the following problem. I have built a flow that creates a SharePoint item when entering data via MS Forms and subsequently added a link to the document (MS Forms Attachment) in a column within the sharepoint Item. Now this SharePoint item is created twice, once without a link and once with a link to the document. Can someone give me a tip why that could be? I don't get an error message either ... I'm grateful for any tip or help.

Greetings

BananaJoe

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Sharepoint-item-is-created-twice/m-p/1218254

Comment: You probably created a different flow and it is still running. Make sure to turn off any other flows that you have created.

Comment: Could you please share your flow here? Otherwise it will be hard to go on troubleshooting.